# Proving the independence of sets in the context of matroid over fields other than $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, matroids

I was going through the text Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et. al. [CLRS] where I came across the following section about matroids.

---

A ***matroid*** is an ordered pair $M = (S, \ell)$ satisfying the following conditions.

1. $S$ is a finite set.
2. $\ell$ is a nonempty family of subsets of $S$, called the ***independent*** subsets of $S$, such that if $В \in \ell$ and $А \subseteq В$, then $A \in \ell$. We say that $\ell$ is ***hereditary*** if it satisfies this property. Note that the empty set $\phi$ is necessarily a member of $\ell$.
3. If $A \in \ell$, $A \in \ell$, and $|A| < |B|$, then there is some element $x \in В — A$ such that $A\cup\{x\} \in \ell$. We say that $M$ satisfies the ***exchange property***.

---

Now here in the definition above I was having a doubt regarding the term ***"independent set/subsets"*** as I have not encountered this term earlier and I was wondering what could its meaning be. Now then I came to [this answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2538074/606943) ,which made me understand that the independence here is quite similar to the concept of ***linearly independent set of vectors*** in vector space. But then again,I face a problem here the set $S$ in matroid (assuming each element is a vector) can be over any field $F$ and I have the experience of working over only real field $\mathbb{R}$.

---

Then in the text there were few example of matroids without proofs such as:

1. Graphic Matroid: $M_G=(S_G,\ell_G)$ for a graph $G=(V,E)$ where $S_G=E$(set of edges of graph $G$). And they say that a set $A\subseteq S_G$ is independent iff it is acyclic.( I do not quite get how  they are getting this "acyclic" condition as equivalent to independence) [details of text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ElgT.png)
2. In the task scheduling problem the authors say that a set $A$ of tasks is ***independent*** if there exists a schedule for these tasks such that no tasks are late.(How are they getting this condition of independence?) [details of text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJKro.png)

---

The above two examples are just to indicate the portion where I am facing the difficulty. I would be quite helpful if some could explain me the concept of deriving the independence of sets in the context of matroids for fields other than $\mathbb{R}$ in a hardcore manner with examples. I am facing this problem as I have not been lucky yet to have a formal matroid course.

---

[CLRS]: *Cormen, Thomas H.; Leiserson, Charles E.; Rivest, Ronald L.; Stein, Clifford*, Introduction to algorithms., Cambridge, MA: MIT Press (ISBN 978-0-262-03384-8/hbk; 978-0-262-53305-8/pbk). xix, 1292 p. (2009). [ZBL1187.68679](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1187.68679).

Comment: 1. is not a property, it's a definition. Possibly the same applies to 2. Note that in both cases you didn't define $\ell_G$, hence it is likely these are definitions. Otherwise those statements make no sense.

Comment: should I include the pages from the text to make it  more clear? I think it would be better.

Comment: Sure. Also the name of the paper and the author would be helpful.

Comment: @freakish I have updated the question, could you please confirm about whether it is the "definition" as you said in *both the cases*.